# access xamp from another pc

Tags: apache, xampp, ip, localhost

Hi I'm sure you already heard this question hundred times. But I really couldn't solve it myself.
I have win 7 and XAMP 3.2.1 I'm buelding a site that I want to test throw another pc via my wifi network.
All the explanations I found sujest that i modify the httpd-xamp.conf file:
change this section:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:    (?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
  </LocationMatch>
```

The problem is that those lines of code doesnt exist on my version.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the local ip after which you can access through the local ip you create. or type in ipconfig in cmd console.
then the ip address you listed there. copy and paste in your browser.
IPv4 Address

```
 Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 1.27.153.141 // copy paster to browser
 Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
 Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 0.0.0.0
```

You also can easily access it through your public IP network as long as you know your router's public IP

Comment: do not forget to set your firewall